# Sozi not working on Inkscape, Ubuntu 20.04 | ImportError: No module named fields

Tags: python, extension, inkscape

I have successfully downloaded and copied Sozi's folder/files into the proper Inkscape's extensions folder, after which -when I try to run Sozi from the Extensions Menu- I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sozi.py", line 31, in <module>
    from sozi.ui import *
  File "/home/geppettvs/.config/inkscape/extensions/sozi/ui.py", line 26, in <module>
ImportError: No module named fields
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Previous similar errors were fixed, something about other modules but I can't find a way to solve this "fields" python module's dependence, which seems to be stopping the script from running.

If you need further information from my system just let me know. I don't know what to append at this very moment.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who is Sozi? Which download link do you use to download sozi's extensions?

Answer (score 2):

The version of Sozi you are trying to install is very outdated. The last version of Sozi that shipped as an Inkscape extension was Sozi 13, released in 2013.

Since 2015, Sozi is a standalone application that runs independently of Inkscape. You can still use Inkscape to create your document, and use Sozi to organize your presentation.

I would advise to install the latest version of Sozi using the [instructions from its official website](https://sozi.baierouge.fr/pages/20-install.html). The recommended place to report issues or discuss about Sozi is [the GitHub page of the project](https://github.com/sozi-projects/Sozi/)

Comment: Hello Guillaume. Thank you for your answer. This is more helpful. So, I guess -from your words- there is no way to run the Inkscape extension? Appreciation a lot for you and thank you for your time.